# How to reject LibreOffice Calc autocomplete suggestion?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, user-interface

LibreOffice Calc likes to aggressive suggest cell content based on a prefix.

It is easy to accept the suggestion by hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

But how to I reject it, which is something that is needed even more often?

There is a perfectly good key for this on the keyboard, namely <kbd>ESC</kbd>, but it does nothing.

N.B.

I do not want to *disable* Autocomplete, I just want to *reject its suggestions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> should nullify the suggestion.

A user has suggested in
[this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/143453/how-reject-autocomplete-suggestion/)
that it would be easier to use the key sequence
<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>,
as the keys are right next to each other.